# why in c# casting object to objects of type T with same value aren't recognized the same?

Tags: c#, generics

I am getting into generics but there is something I don't  understand Here I have this class;

```
    class Node<T>{
        T value;
        Node <T> next,prev;
        public Node(T vl)
        {
          this.value=vl;
          this.next=this.prev=null;
        }
        }
```

I have a class List and a method Insert and it is working fine :

```
 class Lista<T>
    {
        public Node<T> Head, Tail;
        public int Cnt;

        public Lista()
        {
            this.Head = this.Tail = null;
            this.Cnt = 0;
        }



public void Insert(T vl)
    {
        Node<T> nd = new Node<T>(vl);
        if (this.IsEmpty())
            this.Head = this.Tail = nd;
        else
        {
            this.Tail.next = nd;
            nd.prev = this.Tail;
            this.Tail = nd;
        }
        this.Cnt++;
    }


}
```

but I Have a method FindNode:

```
 public Node<T> FindNode(T vl)
        {
            if (this.IsEmpty()) return null;
            Node<T> tmp = this.Head;
            while (tmp != null && ((object)tmp.VL != (object)vl)) tmp = tmp.next;
            return tmp;
        }
```

which finds a Node inside the List now the problem is 
if I have a `Lista<string>` it works fine but if I create a `Lista<int>`
even if the element in list exists while comparing it is ignoring the same values and going next until it goes null , why does that happen ?

Method isEmpty:

```
public bool IsEmpty()
        {
            if (this.Head == null && this.Tail == null) return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Generics was invented to avoid something like `(object)tmp.VL`.

Comment: You haven't overloaded `Equals` so how is C# going to know you consider them the same? It can only check whether the variables refer to the same *instance*

Comment: @SeM I know right but if I say tmp.VL==vl it says that operand== cannot be used to types T and T

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how do I do that could you explain please

Comment: @JohnnyAdams instead of trying to cover up the compilation problem, *fix* it. Override `Equals` and `==`

Comment: @JohnnyAdams furthermore, use properties instead of public fields. Fields are meant to hold private state. They are *not* considered part of a class's contract.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes that's I would normally do , thanks for your advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that for **valuetypes** like `int` in your example you are **boxing** them by casting to object.
Per default, the `==` operator does **ReferenceEquality** and this means that it will never return true in your case because the *boxes* are never the same.

Easiest was to fix this would be to turn this line

```
while (tmp != null && ((object)tmp.VL != (object)vl)) tmp = tmp.next;
```

into this

```
 while (tmp != null && !Equals(tmp.VL , vl)) tmp = tmp.next;
```

This will use the default equality comparer for a certain type and makes your code work as intended.

You could go further by using a generic constraint declared for your class like so:

```
class Lista<T> where T : IEquateable<T>
```

and change the same line like this

```
while (tmp != null && (!tmp.VL.Equals(vl)) tmp = tmp.next;
```

Or make it possible to inject an `IEqualityComparer<T>` into your class

```
  class Lista<T>
  {
       IEqualityComparer<T> _comparer;
       public Lista(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
       {
           _comparer = comparer ?? EuqlityComparer<T>.Default;
       }

       public Node<T> FindNode(T vl)
       {
           if (this.IsEmpty()) return null;
           Node<T> tmp = this.Head;
           while (tmp != null && !_comparer.Equals(tmp.VL, vl) tmp = tmp.next;
           return tmp;
       }
  }
```

Comment: thanks this was simple and  worked like charm , but from the both methods you suggested which one would you recommend to use

Comment: @JohnnyAdams the last one, using the IEqualityComparer is usually common practice. But if you dont need it, the first one is just fine.